# How do I write a function with two long arguments?

Tags: php

Most tutorials I find online tend to use the following format:

**Method 1**

```
$functionargument = <long_argument_goes_here>;
function($functionargument);
```

I personally find this hard to read. I know I won't have a choice if I ever start working for a team with a style guide, but I prefer:

**Method 2**

```
function(
    <long_argument_goes_here>
);
```

I don't know the name of these two methods, but I do know that method 1 is easier to find reference material for, and method 2 is the one I find easier to read, especially as the code gets more and more complex. If I don't see it physically nested, I forget where it came from.

One situation I've never seen in method 2 before is:

**Style 1**

```
$functionargument1 = <long_argument_goes_here>
$functionargument2 = <different_long_argument_goes_here>
function($functionargument1,$functionargument2);
```

I have a guess as to what the method 2 approach should be, but I'm not sure:

**Style 2**

```
function(
    <long_argument_goes_here>
,
    <different_long_argument_goes_here>
);
```

I've never seen a comma floating in the middle of code like that before, but it just feels right to me.

What is the correct name of "method 1" and "method 2"? I'd like to research this further, but I don't have the correct keywords to find it.

Comment: This type of opinion-solicitation question is off-topic for StackOverflow. There are no right answers, just opinion and discussion, based on individuals or teams working with a particular code base.

Comment: @DavidMakogon The name of the style is the thrust of my question. I never asked which style is best.

Comment: Re-read your question: It talks about different styles, and your title even asks "What is the accepted standard" - which is off-topic. Plus you're asking for a style guide reference (another off-topic question). It's not until nearly the end of your question where you ask about a style name (within a style guide reference). If the main point of your question is to discover a style name, it's a bit odd you'd bury that as an additional question at the end. There are plenty of sites to discuss this type of question, such as reddit. Unfortunately, StackOverflow isn't...

Comment: "The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from." ~~ A.S. Tanenbaum

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have paraphrased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the PSR-2 standard, there is a section about [methods](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#44-method-arguments).

It allows you to use

```
public function foo($arg1, &$arg2, $arg3 = [])
{
    // method body
}
```

and if your function names or parameter names are longer:

```
public function aVeryLongMethodName(
    $functionargument1,
    $functionargument2,
    $functionargument3
) {
    // method body
}
```

Comment: just another opinion, in my opinion.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, that's why I used 'You could'...

Comment: PSR is the way to go, at least if you want to stick to one accepted standard.